# Fantasy Kung Fu/Karate movie with combating Dojos

Tags: story-identification, movie, b-movies, martial-arts

Trying to find a fantasy karate/kung-fu movie I only saw a scene from and it had a older Asian lady with white braided hair that went to the ground and her and I think two or three other older people each ran a dojo or something like that and they were fighting to determine who would work for the emperor or something. Anyway, the white haired lady's trainee used her hair as a weapon to fight another guy. I don't know much about the plot as I only saw the one fight scene of the movie a long time ago. the fighters seemed to be either Samurai or Ninja's or maybe both, unsure if the movie was low budget or not. If this is not the appropriate area to post this I apologize.

Comment: If it has fantasy aspects (which a lot of the martial arts movies did), this is a fine place.

Comment: Kind of wondering if the hair lady will turn out to be Lian Nichang. She's a common shared character.

Comment: Check this movie Shinobi : Heart Under Blade (2006), please: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-gdiWYhaecY

The idea of the movie is two Ninja/Samurai villages duking it out so the winner can work for the emperor.

Comment: @jo1storm that's it!! it seems i got some of the details wrong , but the guy with the long sleeves attacking with his hair i'm certain that's it. tried to upvote your comment but accidentally double clicked due to mouse problems and won't let me do so again, Thanks so much, i've been searching for this for years lol

Comment: Ok, accept your answer when you are able.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly *[Shinobi : Heart Under Blade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinobi:_Heart_Under_Blade)* (2006). The plot of the movie is two Ninja/Samurai villages duking it out so the winner can work for the newly crowned emperor.

> Set immediately after the Japanese Sengoku period, Iga and Kouga, two mercenary clans have been waging a vendetta against each other over hundreds of years. Around 1614, Tokugawa Ieyasu, the ruler of Japan and the founder of the Tokugawa Shogunate, perceives the threat posed by the two clans. Attempting to consolidate his reign, he deliberately stirs up their feud by inviting the clans to choose their five best warriors to fight to the death. Designated as the leaders of the two clans respectively, Kouga Gennosuke (Joe Odagiri) and Oboro (Yukie Nakama), who have secretly married, are unwillingly embroiled in the political plot. Hence, they have to make a difficult decision.
>
> Initially, being peaceful and knowing the preciousness of life, they try their utmost to prevent this meaningless and brutal fight by questioning the shogunate's motives. After the deaths of all their comrades, however, they gradually accept their fate. In the last fight, Kouga Gennosuke chooses not to defend himself and allows his lover Oboro to kill him, thus letting the clan of Iga "win". Meanwhile, Ieyasu sends his armies to exterminate the ninja villages. To accomplish Gennosuke's hope of saving them, Oboro implores Tokugawa Ieyasu not to destroy the villages and, as a show of her sincerity, blinds herself, thereby destroying her most powerful weapons, her eyes (which possess a deadly technique called "Piercing Eyes" (破幻之瞳, "Hagen no Dō" lit. "the pupil of annihilation"). Moved profoundly by Oboro, Ieyasu withdraws his armies and issues an injunction to protect the ninja villages. For generations hence, the villages live peacefully.

### Trailer